# How to get iterator number and also element in same loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

For example:I Have following List.

```
ｌist1=["a","b","c","d"]
```

How to get both iterator number(in below code that is iteration) and item of list in the same `for` `loop`.I can write with following two loop .

```
for iteration in len(list1):
    for each_item in list1:
        #logic related to each_item
```

Comment: `for index, item in enumerate(list1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for i,  item in enumerate(list1):
    print(i, item)
```